# A sequence of peculiar palindromes

Tags: number-sequence

My son Robin came up with this: 0550, 1001, 1111, 1221, 1331, 1441, 1551, 2002...

What are the next 4 numbers? Solve it today!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I would say Greg is almost correct but that the actual answer is

> 2112, 2222, 2332, 0000

Because these are

> Palindromic times on a digital clock, in order (e.g, 21:12, 22:22)

Comment: Ahh.  Good call!  Does ROT13(Zl fba Ebova) have anything to do with it?

Comment: @Greg, not sure, can you see a connection? I thought it was just the truth.

Comment: I can not.  I was wondering how you made connection with the second part of you answer (thought that might be why)

Answer (score 4):

> 2112, 2222, 2332, 2442, (2552, 3003) (next 6 for good measure)

Because:

> The middle two numbers increase by one, when they reach `6`, the outside numbers go up by one, the middle numbers go to zero (sort of modulo 6)

Comment: Your observation is correct but there is an everyday reason for it; our answer is therefore more specific.